# direct_mail: fetch content of page does not work

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

i updated a typo3 7 LTS to 8 LTS with direct_mail which is now in version 5.2.2 When i try to create a new newsletter i get the following error: "
An error was encountered.
The plain text content could not be fetched.
The HTML content could not be fetched."

i dont know why this happens. There is no other error message even in develop mode. the problem happens in my local dev and in the life installation.

curl is installed in php (7.0) and i can load the extension list (which uses curl i think). My local dev uses http and the life installation ssl but with public certificate, not self signed.

Any idea where i can find a solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, after a few hours i found the solution. The proxy settings changed from TYPO3 7 LTS to 8 LTS: 
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/Changelog/8.1/Breaking-70056-CurlAndHttpRequestRemoved.html?highlight=proxy

"All proxy-related options are unified within $GLOBALS[TYPO3_CONF_VARS][HTTP][proxy]"

So

```
'HTTP' => [
    'proxy_host' => 'myIP',
    'proxy_port' => 'myPort',
],
```

becomes

```
'HTTP' => [
    'proxy => [
        'proxy_host' => 'myIP',
        'proxy_port' => 'myPort',
    ]
],
```

So my problem is fixed now - perhaps this will help someone to save some time :-)

Answer (score 0):

FYI: In V8, V9 and V10 its simpler:

```
$GLOBALS[TYPO3_CONF_VARS][HTTP][proxy_host]
$GLOBALS[TYPO3_CONF_VARS][HTTP][proxy_port]
```

and if needed, this as well:

```
$GLOBALS[TYPO3_CONF_VARS][HTTP][proxy_user]
$GLOBALS[TYPO3_CONF_VARS][HTTP][proxy_password]
$GLOBALS[TYPO3_CONF_VARS][HTTP][proxy_auth_scheme]
```